# How to modify UI text via script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, text

A simple question: I'm trying to modify UI text (TextMeshPro if that makes any difference) via C# script. I am using the following code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Coins : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text coins;
    void Start()
    {
        coins = GetComponent<Text>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        coins.text = "text";
    }
}
```

I've done a similar thing in Unity 2018 (I'm currently using Unity 2020.2) and it worked there.
For some reason it doesn't work here though. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: `TextMeshPro if that makes any difference` .. well that is a complete different type to `UnityEngine.UI.Text` so .. yeah it makes a difference ^^ Also please describe better what `doesn't work` means exactly

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Changing text in TMP is practicly the same, but you need to add `"using TMPro;"` and also change variable type. The code should look like this:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

public class Coins : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TMP_Text coins;
    void Start()
    {
        coins = GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        coins.text = "text";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To modify `TextMeshPro` components, you have to use `TMP_Text` class.

```
public class Coins : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TMP_Text coins;
    void Start()
    {
         coins = GetComponent<TMP_Text>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
         coins.text = "text"; //or coins.SetText(“text”);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference the tmp text component instead of the normal Unity text one:
Instead of `GetComponent<Text>();` do `GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();`

Of course don’t forget:

`using TMPro;`

on top of your code.